# Wrong ordering of class values in Weka Prediction Distribution

Tags: java, classification, weka

I added the class-attribute of my dataset like following (same for train- and testset):

```
ArrayList<String> nomValues = new ArrayList<>();
nomValues.add("1");
nomValues.add("0");
datasetBinary_train.insertAttributeAt(new Attribute("class", nomValues), datasetBinary_train.numAttributes());
```

So I assume the value 1 to be at position 0 and the value 0 at position 1.

Thus I assume that the `double[]` I get with `NominalPrediction.distribution()` will have the class-probability for class "1" at position 0.

Examining the classification-result it seems to be vice versa.

One Prediction is looking like this.

> NOM: 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.6081479321383793 0.3918520678616207

where 1 is the actual class and 0 the predicted class (then the weight and next the distribution). I would think that a higher probability for the label "0" is observed which means that the probability for the instance labeled as "0" is shown at index 0

The Evaluation header says

> @attribute (...)
>
> @attribute class {1,0}

So until there it has the right order.

Can someone tell me how the attribute-values are sorted in the Evaluation? How to ensure that the right one is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing labels with label indices (Weka uses 0-based indices internally to represent labels):

`NOM: <actual label index> <predicted label index> <weight> <distribution>`

The actual label index is 1.0 ("0"), the predicted index is 0.0 ("1"), the weight is 1.0 and the distribution is "0.61 0.39". Based on the distribution, the first label gets predicted (0.0 or "1").

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really confusing.. But yes it makes sense... Is this documented somewhere? I didn't find the format of the output in the api. IMO It is worth to be mentioned in the description of the toString()-Method of the Nominatprediction for clarification

Comment: The Prediction classes (numeric and nominal) don't have access to the dataset structure, therefore the label cannot be output, unfortunately. This output is more for debugging purposes as for anything else. BTW using numbers as labels adds a whole lot of confusion in the first place. ;-)

Comment: I thought it is common to have "0" as false and "1" as true.. Unfortunately this will ever create this confusion.. Although it makes absolutely sense and is easier than output the label itself (as it can be any sequence of chars which might be harder to read).. You just have to know it... :)

Comment: a low-brainer to overcome this is to have the class-attribute like {0,1} *facepalming*